# Combine instantiate with lean tween

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I want to scale an object using lean tween but I am also just instantiating it.

How can I combine the lines of code below? In other words I want to scale/animate the prefab while I'm instantiating it.

```
//this line instantiates the Gem
gemList1.Add(Instantiate(Gem, new Vector2((xPos_Hole1 + (Random.Range(-20, 20))) * 2.0F, (-229 + (20 * i))), Quaternion.identity));

//This line animates the GEM by scaling it
LeanTween.scale(Gem, new Vector3(1.7f, 1.7f, 1.7f), 5f).setEase(LeanTweenType.easeOutBounce);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate the GameObject, save the result to a temporary variable. Add that temporary variable to the list then also use that temporary variable in the `LeanTween.scale` function.

```
//this line instantiates the Gem
GameObject tempObj = Instantiate(Gem, new Vector2((xPos_Hole1 + (Random.Range(-20, 20))) * 2.0F, (-229 + (20 * i))), Quaternion.identity);

//this line add the instantiated Gem to the List
gemList1.Add(tempObj);

//This line animates the GEM by scaling it
LeanTween.scale(tempObj, new Vector3(1.7f, 1.7f, 1.7f), 5f).setEase(LeanTweenType.easeOutBounce);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer